# Audio playback techniques to preserve .wav audio data while providing adequate info?

Tags: audio

OK, seems like an audio-geeky question, but is there any tool or format to implement an audio playback platform as follows?

```
Audio player  >>>>.WAV file read----No external metafile>>>>Play directly
                          |
                          |
     External metafile with the same filename detected
                          |
                          V
          Load song info based on the metafile
                          |
                          |
                          V
              Play with media info shown
```

The reason behind this is due to the fact that a WAV header is limited due to the specification, and also lossy formats are not a good idea for music collectors. Based on my explorations of Kodi/XBMC, .nfo seems can do the job, but there should be a trivial approach accomplishing this. Any suggestions?

Comment: "a WAV header is limited due to the specification" [What.](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/RIFF.html)

Comment: Just but your information in the filename? Your question is pretty vague in addition there are other lossless formats that support metainformation.

Comment: no album art, for example. and also i prefer the native WAVE format.

Comment: "Load song info based on the metafile" means the file contains only links would be fine, if the player can download actual info from the links and compose a good display while playing.

Comment: And that is .aiff files, folks. Thanks to other unknown inspirations.